# Why would $P( \cdot|X=x)$ being a measure depend on the set $A$ in $P(A|X=x)$?

Tags: probability-theory

I have some doubts on the following paragraph.

[image]

Where $P(A|X=x)$ was defined as $E(1_{A}|X=x)=f(x)$, where $f:Range(X)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is measurable, and $f(X)=E(1_{A}|X)$

Why would the null set on which $f$ may not be defined, depend on $A$? Is there a simple example?

Second, what do they mean by «if the sigma algebra can be approximated(...) then there is hope»?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I interpret $P[A \mid X=x]$ as $E[1_A \mid X](\omega(x))$ where $\omega(x)$ is any element of $X^{-1}(\{ x \})$. The choice of $\omega(x)$ cannot matter, because $E[1_A \mid X]$ is necessarily constant on level sets of $X$, but still $E[1_A \mid X]$ can be modified on null sets at no loss as long as it remains $\sigma(X)$-measurable. This can be a problem if we modify $X^{-1}(\{ x \})$ on a null set in such a way that it overlaps more or less with $A$ than it did before.

Comment: @Ian thanks for your comment. I'm just having some difficulty in understanding your last sentence... could you please elaborate a bit more on the part «in such a way that it overlaps (...)»?

Comment: Suppose $X^{-1}(\{ x \})$ is null. It actually can be any null set whatsoever, without changing the distribution of $X$. In particular, it could be contained in $A$, or it could have empty intersection with $A$. In the former case, presumably $P[A \mid X=x]=1$; in the latter case presumably $P[A \mid X=x]=0$. $E[1_A \mid X]$ (which is really the well-defined object) can't see such fine details.

Comment: @Ian Ah! Thanks!!! ;)